# pytorch equivalent to keras Dot, with axes argument

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I need to convert this keras operation to pytorch:

```
user_vec = keras.layers.Dot((1,1))([user_vecs,user_att])
```

Suppose user_vecs has shape (2,5,10) and user_att has shape (2,5). The output has shape (2,10).

pytorch `inner` only works on the last dimension of the two inputs- I'm wondering if I should permute my axes and call `inner` then permute back, or if there's a better way.

```
user_vecs = user_vecs.permute(0,2,1)
torch.inner(user_vecs, user_att)
```

However, this is returning a tensor of shape (2,10,2).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest way to accomplish this is using `einsum`:

```
user_att = user_att.unsqueeze(2)
torch.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', user_vecs, user_att)
```